# Handling unicode in python when working with Google APIs through GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, encoding, google-api

I'm working with Google APIs through Google App Engine and Python.
I have problem with unsupported characters being encoded:

```
å → u'\xe5'
ä → u'\xe4'
ö → u'\xf6'
```

When I logg data, the strings are shown correctly but when working the encoded data, I get errors.

I want to get object and delete it:

```
obj = get_obj()             #obj = {u'name': u'G\xe4ster'}
logging.debug(obj["name"])  #Gäster
try:
  delete_obj( obj["name"] )
except Exception as e:
  logging.debug(type(e))    #<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>
  logging.debug(e)          #u'\xe4'
```

Comment: This is perfectly normal `repr` form for on-screen display. `u'\xE4'` is absolutely the same value as `u'ä'`. How is this a problem?

Comment: What is the traceback from the `KeyError`?

Comment: KeyError is likely because the obj does not have `'name'`

Comment: Text updated - hopefully clearing out the questions